# Obter "ondas" da frequência de som ou música

Tags: javascript

Como faço para exibir as ondas sonoras de qualquer som (música)? Não sei se é possível obter isso com JS ou alguma outra linguagem. Ondas desse tipo:

[image: ondas sonoras]

Um exemplo é [como SoundCloud faz](https://soundcloud.com/rocketcast/rc22), exibindo uma espécie de onda do áudio que está sendo executado.

Quero armazenar no meu servidor/site, ou seja, tendo o áudio localmente e exibir para o visitante a frequência do som.

Comment: Cara, sua dúvida está ampla demais. Como você vai receber esse som? Como você quer apresentar essas ondas? Poderia tentar especificar um pouco mais?

Comment: Acredito que não tenha como fazer isso da forma correta sem ter um hardware especial para captar o som, caso seja externo. O que normalmente programas comuns fazem é detectar as mudanças de volume da música e trabalhar com animações em cima dessas informações simulando as ondas sonoras.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar fiz edição na minha descrição, obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @DirtyOldMan vc sabe o nome de algum programa ou equipamento que realizam isso ?

Comment: @DirtyOldMan, na verdade eu imagino que ele capte a frequência de cada trecho da música e vai gerando o gráfico (ou animação) que ele deseja, não? Um arquivo mp3, por exemplo, contém informações suficientes pra isso. Por isso eu perguntei como ele vai receber esses dados...

Comment: Inclusive, uma das opções, é ele já ter as informações dessas animações prontas e só enviar um json, por exemplo, pra tratar no front-end, enquanto o som toca...

Comment: Já vi isto feito em outras linguagens e sempre me pareceram bem eficientes, acredito que um hardware só para isso seja exagero, desculpe a sinceridade @DirtyOldMan

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A [API de áudio do HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) permite esse tipo de visualização, com bastante flexibilidade. Eis um exemplo adaptado de um [tutorial da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API), pegando o áudio de um elemento `<audio>` e desenhando a visualização num `<canvas>`:

> **AVISO:** O exemplo abaixo não funciona mais inline porque utiliza um arquivo de áudio de outro domínio, causando um aviso de *`MediaElementAudioSource` outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions* no Chrome (e provavelmente algo semelhante em outros browsers). Se você testar no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento ou servidor, com arquivos locais, funciona. Estranhamente, no preview de edição aqui do site também funciona.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
source.connect(analyser);
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

// CORS
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

analyser.fftSize = 1024;
var bufferLength = analyser.fftSize;
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var sliceWidth = w * 1.0 / bufferLength;
canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    
function draw() {
    drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    canvasCtx.beginPath();

    var x = 0;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
        var y = v * h/2;
        if(i === 0) {
            canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
            canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        x += sliceWidth;
    }
    canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
    canvasCtx.stroke();
};

draw();
```

```html
<audio controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    <source src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Goldberg_variations_1_start.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<canvas width="600" height="150"></canvas>
```

<sup>Crédito do áudio: [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Goldberg_variations_1_start.ogg), trecho inicial da Variação 1 das Variações Goldberg de Bach, BWV 988</sup>

Comment: muito obrigado, vc me ajudou muitoooo !! Parabéns. era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando.

Answer (score 16):

Se a "onda" do áudio for estática (sem animação), você pode usar o [**WaveSurfer**](http://wavesurfer-js.org)

- Download: http://wavesurfer-js.org/dist/wavesurfer.min.js
- Documentação: https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/blob/master/README.md

Exemplo:

> @bfavaretto permita-me usar o mesmo áudio que o seu? :)

```js
var wavesurfer   = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
var pausePlayBtn = document.getElementById('playPause');
var stopBtn      = document.getElementById('stop');
var progress     = document.getElementById('progress');
var isPaused     = true;

wavesurfer.init({
    container: document.querySelector('#wave'),
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});

wavesurfer.on('loading', function (status) {
    if (status === 100) {
        progress.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        progress.innerHTML = status + "%";
    }
});

wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    isPaused = true;

    wavesurfer.play();
    pausePlayBtn.innerHTML = "Pause";

    pausePlayBtn.onclick = function() {
       isPaused = isPaused ? false : true;

       pausePlayBtn.innerHTML = isPaused ? "Pause" : "Play";
       wavesurfer.playPause();
    };
    
    stopBtn.onclick = function() {
       isPaused = false;
       pausePlayBtn.innerHTML = "Play";
       wavesurfer.stop();
    };
});

wavesurfer.load('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Goldberg_variations_1_start.ogg');
```

```html
<script src="//wavesurfer-js.org/dist/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<div id="wave">
    <p id="progress">0</p>
</div>
<button id="playPause">Play</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

<sup>Crédito do áudio: [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Goldberg_variations_1_start.ogg), trecho inicial da Variação 1 das Variações Goldberg de Bach, BWV 988</sup>

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vc tb me ajudou bastante. Não tenho palavras p agradecer vc e o bfavaretto, muito obrigado !!

Comment: Guilherme, seu exemplo quebrou, provavelmente quando a wikimedia mudou a política de acesso (eu editei a minha um tempo atrás por isso; veja meu último edit). O wavesurfer permite setar `audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";` em algum lugar? Isso deve resolver.

Comment: @bfavaretto infelzimente a solução parece que tem quer do lado servidor, depois vou ver melhor.

Comment: Ué, agora parece que está funcionando?! Deve ter sido um problema temporário em algum dos arquivos externos.