# Como pausar animação CSS enquanto a música está parada?

Tags: css, html5, css3, html5-audio

Eu fiz um exemplo:

```js
function play() {
    //Fazer animação
}

function pause() {
    //Para animação, ficar toda linha roxa;
}
```

```css
#animacao {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

#bloco {
  display: block;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 09px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #9b59b6;
  position: absolute;
  animation: audio-wave 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

#bloco:nth-child(1) {
left: 00px;
animation-delay: 0.0s;
}
#bloco:nth-child(2) {
left: 11px;
animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

#bloco:nth-child(3) {
left: 22px;
animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#bloco:nth-child(4) {
left: 33px;
animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

#bloco:nth-child(5) {
left: 44px;
animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

#bloco:nth-child(6) {
left: 55px;
animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes audio-wave {
    0% {height:5px;transform:translateY(0px);background:#9b59b6;}
    25% {height:40px;transform:translateY(20px);background:#3498db;}
/*effect is to animate the height of each span from 5px to 30px*/
/*translateY makes Y axis move down to give the effect that it is growing from the center*/

    50% {height:5px;transform:translateY(0px);background:#9b59b6;}
    100% {height:5px;transform:translateY(0px);background:#9b59b6;}
}
```

```html
<div id="animacao">
  <div id="bloco"></div>
  <div id="bloco"></div>
  <div id="bloco"></div>
  <div id="bloco"></div>
  <div id="bloco"></div>
  <div id="bloco"></div>
</div>

<br>

<audio id="player" controls="controls" onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" src="http://ianreah.apphb.com/sounds/movement%20proposition.mp3"> </audio>
```

Eu vi outro exemplo da função quando ela para a música e toca a música [aqui](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html).

Quando pausar a música, ele deve ficar toda linha roxa e não azul.

Antes de tocar a música deve ficar toda linha roxa também.

Ele só pode fazer animação enquanto a música toca.

Alguma idéia ?

Comment: **Relacionado/alternativas:** [Obter “ondas” da frequência de som ou música](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57870/3635)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uma alternativa sem precisar importar o jQuery:

   ```js
     
     var audio = document.getElementById("player");
     var animacao = document.getElementById("animacao");
     
     audio.addEventListener("click", function() {
          if (audio.paused) {
              audio.play();
          } else {
              audio.pause();
          }
     });
     
     audio.addEventListener("play", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio for pausado
     audio.addEventListener("pause", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio terminar
     audio.addEventListener("ended", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio não puder continuar, talvez não esteja recebendo dados e esteja aguardando
     audio.addEventListener("suspend", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio não puder ser reproduzido
     audio.addEventListener("error", detectStatus);
     
     var reclass = /(^|\s)paused(\s|$)/g;
     
     function detectStatus()
     {
          if (!audio.paused) {
              animacao.className = String(audio.className).replace(reclass, "");
          } else if (!reclass.test(animacao.className)) {
              animacao.className += " paused";
          }
     }
   ```

   ```css
     
     #animacao {
       position: relative;
       margin: 30px;
     }
     .bloco {
       display: block;
       bottom: 0px;
       width: 09px;
       height: 5px;
       background: #9b59b6;
       position: absolute;
       animation: audio-wave 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
     }
     .paused > .bloco {
       -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
       -o-animation-play-state: paused;
       -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
       -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
       animation-play-state: paused;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(1) {
       left: 00px;
       animation-delay: 0.0s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(2) {
       left: 11px;
       animation-delay: 0.1s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(3) {
       left: 22px;
       animation-delay: 0.2s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(4) {
       left: 33px;
       animation-delay: 0.3s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(5) {
       left: 44px;
       animation-delay: 0.4s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(6) {
       left: 55px;
       animation-delay: 0.5s;
     }
     @keyframes audio-wave {
       0% {
         height: 5px;
         transform: translateY(0px);
         background: #9b59b6;
       }
       25% {
         height: 40px;
         transform: translateY(20px);
         background: #3498db;
       }
       /*effect is to animate the height of each span from 5px to 30px*/
       /*translateY makes Y axis move down to give the effect that it is growing from the center*/
       50% {
         height: 5px;
         transform: translateY(0px);
         background: #9b59b6;
       }
       100% {
         height: 5px;
         transform: translateY(0px);
         background: #9b59b6;
       }
     }
   ```

   ```html
     
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div id="animacao" class="paused">
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
     </div>
     
     <br>
     <audio id="player" controls src="http://ianreah.apphb.com/sounds/movement%20proposition.mp3"></audio>
   ```
2. Você também pode optar pode remover a animação assim ao invés de pausar o efeito é come se ele reiniciasse:

   ```js
     
     var audio = document.getElementById("player");
     var animacao = document.getElementById("animacao");
     
     audio.addEventListener("click", function() {
          if (audio.paused) {
              audio.play();
          } else {
              audio.pause();
          }
     });
     
     audio.addEventListener("play", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio for pausado
     audio.addEventListener("pause", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio terminar
     audio.addEventListener("ended", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio não puder continuar, talvez não esteja recebendo dados e esteja aguardando
     audio.addEventListener("suspend", detectStatus);
     
     //Para a animação se o audio não puder ser reproduzido
     audio.addEventListener("error", detectStatus);
     
     var reclass = /(^|\s)animado(\s|$)/g;
     
     function detectStatus()
     {
          if (audio.paused) {
              animacao.className = String(audio.className).replace(reclass, "");
          } else if (!reclass.test(animacao.className)) {
              animacao.className += " animado";
          }
     }
   ```

   ```css
     
     #animacao {
       position: relative;
       margin: 30px;
     }
     .bloco {
       display: block;
       bottom: 0px;
       width: 09px;
       height: 5px;
       background: #9b59b6;
       position: absolute;
     }
     .animado > .bloco {
       animation: audio-wave 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(1) {
       left: 00px;
       animation-delay: 0.0s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(2) {
       left: 11px;
       animation-delay: 0.1s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(3) {
       left: 22px;
       animation-delay: 0.2s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(4) {
       left: 33px;
       animation-delay: 0.3s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(5) {
       left: 44px;
       animation-delay: 0.4s;
     }
     .bloco:nth-child(6) {
       left: 55px;
       animation-delay: 0.5s;
     }
     @keyframes audio-wave {
       0% {
         height: 5px;
         transform: translateY(0px);
         background: #9b59b6;
       }
       25% {
         height: 40px;
         transform: translateY(20px);
         background: #3498db;
       }
       /*effect is to animate the height of each span from 5px to 30px*/
       /*translateY makes Y axis move down to give the effect that it is growing from the center*/
       50% {
         height: 5px;
         transform: translateY(0px);
         background: #9b59b6;
       }
       100% {
         height: 5px;
         transform: translateY(0px);
         background: #9b59b6;
       }
     }
   ```

   ```html
     
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div id="animacao">
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
       <div class="bloco"></div>
     </div>
     
     <br>
     <audio id="player" controls src="http://ianreah.apphb.com/sounds/movement%20proposition.mp3"></audio>
   ```
3. Algumas outras alternativas:

   [Obter "ondas" da frequência de som ou música](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57870/3635)

Answer (score 1):

Assim você consegue pausar a animação use a ferramenta snipet, para fazer seus js pois links externos podem parar de funcionar

```js
$('video').bind('play', function (e) {
  $('.bloco').toggleClass('paused');
});


$('video').bind('pause', function (e) {
  $('.bloco').toggleClass('paused');
});
```

```css
#animacao {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}
.bloco {
  display: block;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 09px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #9b59b6;
  position: absolute;
  animation: audio-wave 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.paused {
  -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.bloco:nth-child(1) {
  left: 00px;
  animation-delay: 0.0s;
}
.bloco:nth-child(2) {
  left: 11px;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.bloco:nth-child(3) {
  left: 22px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.bloco:nth-child(4) {
  left: 33px;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.bloco:nth-child(5) {
  left: 44px;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.bloco:nth-child(6) {
  left: 55px;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes audio-wave {
  0% {
    height: 5px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    background: #9b59b6;
  }
  25% {
    height: 40px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    background: #3498db;
  }
  /*effect is to animate the height of each span from 5px to 30px*/
  /*translateY makes Y axis move down to give the effect that it is growing from the center*/
  50% {
    height: 5px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    background: #9b59b6;
  }
  100% {
    height: 5px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    background: #9b59b6;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animacao">
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  <div class="bloco"></div>
</div>

<br>
<video id="video" controls="" preload="none" mediagroup="myVideoGroup">
</video>
```

Comment: Oi @Marco Vinicius Soares, tem como chamar função próprio botão play do html5 player ?

Comment: assim? fiz uma edição

Comment: Tive que fazer outra edição pra não bugar no pause

Comment: Oi @Marcos Vinicius Soares Dalabla, perfect !