# Obter “ondas” da frequência de som ou música em Streaming

Tags: javascript, streaming

Eu estava olhando este outro post (Link abaixo no final) na comunidade e me chamou a atenção, tentei utilizar para Streaming mas simplesmente nem o áudio quis tocar, e me recordo que bem antigamente tentei fazer algo similar a isso, poderiam fazer uma pequena explicação do que dá de errado quando se usa em um streaming, tipo, de um Web Rádio por exemplo?

[Obter "ondas" da frequência de som ou música](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57870/obter-ondas-da-frequ%C3%AAncia-de-som-ou-m%C3%BAsica)

```js
 // criando objeto <audio> e configurando
 var audio = new Audio();
 audio.src = 'link streaming';
 audio.controls = true;
 audio.loop = false;
 audio.autoplay = true;
 // estabelecendo variaveis
 var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
 // inicializando o player depois da pagina ter carregado
 window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
 function initMp3Player(){
  document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
  context = new AudioContext(); // Instancia do objeto AudioContext
  analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // Metodo AnalyserNode
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // Reencaminhar a reprodução de áudio para o gráfico de processamento do AudioContext
  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  frameLooper();
 }
 function frameLooper(){
  window.RequestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // limpa as barras
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // cores das barras
  bars = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
   bar_x = i * 3;
   bar_width = 2;
   bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
   //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // altura e largura
   ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
 }
```

```css
player{ width:500px; height:60px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; }
player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;  }
player > canvas{ width:500px; height:30px; background:#002D3C; float:left; }
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <div id="audio"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Não tem uma resposta simples, na verdade estou considerando sua perguntas como ampla de mais, em Streaming vai depender de muitas coisas, geralmente terá que saber qual é o formato codificado, qual é a taxa de amostragem do áudio, quantos bits, etc, e lembre-se, você não terá o áudio completo só terá pedaços dele sendo enviado de tempos em tempos... Talvez se editar a pergunta e colocar o seu código podemos entender melhor o que está acontecendo.

Comment: eu inseri o meu código antigo que na época estava tentando, mas acho que hoje em dia não funciona mais, esqueci de colocar, o formato é mp3  128 Kbps 48000hz stereo

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Obter a frequencia a partir de um vetor no dominio da frequencia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249250/obter-a-frequencia-a-partir-de-um-vetor-no-dominio-da-frequencia)