# O que é TypedArray? Quais são as vantagens de usá-los, em relação ao Array tradicional?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Eu estava lendo na MDN sobre [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) e vi que várias classes derivam deste.

Classes que derivam de `TypeArray`:

- Int8Array
- Uint8Array
- Uint8ClampedArray
- Int16Array
- Uint16Array
- Int32Array
- Uint32Array
- Float32Array
- Float64Array

Pelo que entendi, cada um desses "arrays" aceitam um tipo diferente de entrada.

Um teste com `Int8Array`:

```js
var arr = new Int8Array(4);

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 2.5; 
arr[3] = "X2.5"; 


console.log(arr, arr.constructor.name);
```

No caso acima, `2.5` como o valor `string`, foram convertidos para `int`.

Tendo em vista que esses `arrays` possuem esse tipo de comportamento, eu gostaria de tirar umas dúvidas:

- Em que casos eu deveria usar os `TypedArray` ao invés do `Array` padrão do Javascript? Gostaria de exemplos
- Existe algum ganho de performance ao usar um `TypedArray` ao invés de usar o `Array`?
- Gostaria de saber sobre a compatibilidade e [polyfills](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194857/o-que-%C3%A9-polyfill) sobre os mesmos.

Comment: Outra diferença é a inicialização. Comparando por exemplo `new Int8Array(4)` a `new Array(4)` em que neste ultimo os elementos ficam todos como `undefined`. Assim como também definem o tamanho de cada elemento do array em bytes

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, @Isac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Em que casos eu deveria usar os TypedArray ao invés do Array padrão do Javascript? Gostaria de exemplos

A [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Web_APIs_using_typed_arrays) dá 3 exemplos: as APIs do [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsArrayBuffer()), do [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()) e do [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData). E eu me lembro de um 4º que já postei aqui no site em *[Obter "ondas" da frequência de som ou música](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57870/obter-ondas-da-frequ%C3%AAncia-de-som-ou-m%C3%BAsica/57880#57880)*, ligados a um [componente das APIs de áudio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode).

> Existe algum ganho de performance ao usar um TypedArray ao invés de usar o Array?

Sim. Basicamente essas arrays funcionam alocando um bloco de memória para os dados e mapeando esse bloco de acordo com os tipos. Como cada tipo tem tamanho fixo, é possível obter o valor de qualquer índice da array em tempo constante. Já as arrays comuns do JS não são tipadas, e localizar valores nelas é menos eficiente por natureza.

> Gostaria de saber sobre a compatibilidade e polyfills sobre os mesmos.

O suporte é bem amplo, vai até o IE 10, versões iniciais do FF e Chrome, e Safari 5.1. Também tem bom suporte em mobile. Veja o primeiro link desta resposta, no fim do artigo tem uma tabela de compatibilidade.

Sobre polyfills, não creio que façam muito sentido neste caso. Se o objetivo das arrays tipadas é ganhar performance, construir um polyfill para esse recurso só significaria perder mais performance ainda.